Issues with grDevices::col2rgb(colors) in custom CellChat function in R
I am trying to make a custom function based on the CellChat v1.6.1 function netVisual_heatmap(). I wanted to make the font size of the legend editable as is the case for the other text. I only made a small modification in the function and set environment(netVisual_heatmapCustom) <- asNamespace("CellChat") but it now keeps throwing the error: Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colors) : invalid color name 'Reds'.
This is the source code of the function:
function (object, comparison = c(1, 2), measure = c("count", 
  "weight"), signaling = NULL, slot.name = c("netP", "net"), 
  color.use = NULL, color.heatmap = c("Reds"), title.name = NULL, 
  width = NULL, height = NULL, font.size = 8, font.size.title = 10, 
  cluster.rows = FALSE, cluster.cols = FALSE, sources.use = NULL, 
  targets.use = NULL, remove.isolate = FALSE, row.show = NULL, 
  col.show = NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(measure)) {
    measure <- match.arg(measure)
  }
  slot.name <- match.arg(slot.name)
  if (is.list(object@net[[1]])) {
    message("Do heatmap based on a merged object \n")
    obj1 <- object@net[[comparison[1]]][[measure]]
    obj2 <- object@net[[comparison[2]]][[measure]]
    net.diff <- obj2 - obj1
    if (measure == "count") {
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = "Differential number of interactions"
      }
    }
    else if (measure == "weight") {
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = "Differential interaction strength"
      }
    }
    legend.name = "Relative values"
  }
  else {
    message("Do heatmap based on a single object \n")
    if (!is.null(signaling)) {
      net.diff <- slot(object, slot.name)$prob[, , signaling]
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = paste0(signaling, " signaling network")
      }
      legend.name <- "Communication Prob."
    }
    else if (!is.null(measure)) {
      net.diff <- object@net[[measure]]
      if (measure == "count") {
        if (is.null(title.name)) {
          title.name = "Number of interactions"
        }
      }
      else if (measure == "weight") {
        if (is.null(title.name)) {
          title.name = "Interaction strength"
        }
      }
      legend.name <- title.name
    }
  }
  net <- net.diff
  if ((!is.null(sources.use)) | (!is.null(targets.use))) {
    df.net <- reshape2::melt(net, value.name = "value")
    colnames(df.net)[1:2] <- c("source", "target")
    if (!is.null(sources.use)) {
      if (is.numeric(sources.use)) {
        sources.use <- rownames(net.diff)[sources.use]
      }
      df.net <- subset(df.net, source %in% sources.use)
    }
    if (!is.null(targets.use)) {
      if (is.numeric(targets.use)) {
        targets.use <- rownames(net.diff)[targets.use]
      }
      df.net <- subset(df.net, target %in% targets.use)
    }
    cells.level <- rownames(net.diff)
    df.net$source <- factor(df.net$source, levels = cells.level)
    df.net$target <- factor(df.net$target, levels = cells.level)
    df.net$value[is.na(df.net$value)] <- 0
    net <- tapply(df.net[["value"]], list(df.net[["source"]], 
      df.net[["target"]]), sum)
  }
  net[is.na(net)] <- 0
  if (is.null(color.use)) {
    color.use <- scPalette(ncol(net))
  }
  names(color.use) <- colnames(net)
  color.use.row <- color.use
  color.use.col <- color.use
  if (remove.isolate) {
    idx1 <- which(Matrix::rowSums(net) == 0)
    idx2 <- which(Matrix::colSums(net) == 0)
    if (length(idx1) > 0) {
      net <- net[-idx1, ]
      color.use.row <- color.use.row[-idx1]
    }
    if (length(idx2) > 0) {
      net <- net[, -idx2]
      color.use.col <- color.use.col[-idx2]
    }
  }
  mat <- net
  if (!is.null(row.show)) {
    mat <- mat[row.show, ]
    color.use.row <- color.use.row[row.show]
  }
  if (!is.null(col.show)) {
    mat <- mat[, col.show]
    color.use.col <- color.use.col[col.show]
  }
  if (min(mat) < 0) {
    color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(min(mat), 0, max(mat)), 
      c(color.heatmap[1], "#f7f7f7", color.heatmap[2]))
    colorbar.break <- c(round(min(mat, na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", 
      "\\1", min(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1), 0, round(max(mat, 
      na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", "\\1", 
      max(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1))
  }
  else {
    if (length(color.heatmap) == 3) {
      color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(0, min(mat), max(mat)), 
        color.heatmap)
    }
    else if (length(color.heatmap) == 2) {
      color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(min(mat), max(mat)), 
        color.heatmap)
    }
    else if (length(color.heatmap) == 1) {
      color.heatmap.use = (grDevices::colorRampPalette((RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 9, 
        name = color.heatmap))))(100)
    }
    colorbar.break <- c(round(min(mat, na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", 
      "\\1", min(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1), round(max(mat, 
      na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", "\\1", 
      max(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1))
  }
  df.col <- data.frame(group = colnames(mat))
  rownames(df.col) <- colnames(mat)
  df.row <- data.frame(group = rownames(mat))
  rownames(df.row) <- rownames(mat)
  col_annotation <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = df.col, col = list(group = color.use.col), 
    which = "column", show_legend = FALSE, show_annotation_name = FALSE, 
    simple_anno_size = grid::unit(0.2, "cm"))
  row_annotation <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = df.row, col = list(group = color.use.row), 
    which = "row", show_legend = FALSE, show_annotation_name = FALSE, 
    simple_anno_size = grid::unit(0.2, "cm"))
  ha1 = rowAnnotation(Strength = anno_barplot(rowSums(abs(mat)), 
    border = FALSE, gp = gpar(fill = color.use.row, col = color.use.row)), 
    show_annotation_name = FALSE)
  ha2 = HeatmapAnnotation(Strength = anno_barplot(colSums(abs(mat)), 
    border = FALSE, gp = gpar(fill = color.use.col, col = color.use.col)), 
    show_annotation_name = FALSE)
  if (sum(abs(mat) > 0) == 1) {
    color.heatmap.use = c("white", color.heatmap.use)
  }
  else {
    mat[mat == 0] <- NA
  }
  ht1 = Heatmap(mat, col = color.heatmap.use, na_col = "white", 
    name = legend.name, bottom_annotation = col_annotation, 
    left_annotation = row_annotation, top_annotation = ha2, 
    right_annotation = ha1, cluster_rows = cluster.rows, 
    cluster_columns = cluster.rows, row_names_side = "left", 
    row_names_rot = 0, row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size), 
    column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size), column_title = title.name, 
    column_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size.title), 
    column_names_rot = 90, row_title = "Sources (Sender)", 
    row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size.title), row_title_rot = 90, 
    heatmap_legend_param = list(title_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8, 
      fontface = "plain"), title_position = "leftcenter-rot", 
      border = NA, legend_height = unit(20, "mm"), labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8), 
      grid_width = unit(2, "mm")))
  return(ht1)
}


And this is what I changed it to. Note the only modification is in heatmap_legend_param where I changed fontsize = 8 to fontsize = font.size for title_gp and labels_gp.
netVisual_heatmapCustom <- function (object, comparison = c(1, 2), measure = c("count", 
                                                    "weight"), signaling = NULL, slot.name = c("netP", "net"), 
          color.use = NULL, color.heatmap = c("Reds"), title.name = NULL, 
          width = NULL, height = NULL, font.size = 8, font.size.title = 10, 
          cluster.rows = FALSE, cluster.cols = FALSE, sources.use = NULL, 
          targets.use = NULL, remove.isolate = FALSE, row.show = NULL, 
          col.show = NULL) 
{
  if (!is.null(measure)) {
    measure <- match.arg(measure)
  }
  slot.name <- match.arg(slot.name)
  if (is.list(object@net[[1]])) {
    message("Do heatmap based on a merged object \n")
    obj1 <- object@net[[comparison[1]]][[measure]]
    obj2 <- object@net[[comparison[2]]][[measure]]
    net.diff <- obj2 - obj1
    if (measure == "count") {
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = "Differential number of interactions"
      }
    }
    else if (measure == "weight") {
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = "Differential interaction strength"
      }
    }
    legend.name = "Relative values"
  }
  else {
    message("Do heatmap based on a single object \n")
    if (!is.null(signaling)) {
      net.diff <- slot(object, slot.name)$prob[, , signaling]
      if (is.null(title.name)) {
        title.name = paste0(signaling, " signaling network")
      }
      legend.name <- "Communication Prob."
    }
    else if (!is.null(measure)) {
      net.diff <- object@net[[measure]]
      if (measure == "count") {
        if (is.null(title.name)) {
          title.name = "Number of interactions"
        }
      }
      else if (measure == "weight") {
        if (is.null(title.name)) {
          title.name = "Interaction strength"
        }
      }
      legend.name <- title.name
    }
  }
  net <- net.diff
  if ((!is.null(sources.use)) | (!is.null(targets.use))) {
    df.net <- reshape2::melt(net, value.name = "value")
    colnames(df.net)[1:2] <- c("source", "target")
    if (!is.null(sources.use)) {
      if (is.numeric(sources.use)) {
        sources.use <- rownames(net.diff)[sources.use]
      }
      df.net <- subset(df.net, source %in% sources.use)
    }
    if (!is.null(targets.use)) {
      if (is.numeric(targets.use)) {
        targets.use <- rownames(net.diff)[targets.use]
      }
      df.net <- subset(df.net, target %in% targets.use)
    }
    cells.level <- rownames(net.diff)
    df.net$source <- factor(df.net$source, levels = cells.level)
    df.net$target <- factor(df.net$target, levels = cells.level)
    df.net$value[is.na(df.net$value)] <- 0
    net <- tapply(df.net[["value"]], list(df.net[["source"]], 
                                          df.net[["target"]]), sum)
  }
  net[is.na(net)] <- 0
  if (is.null(color.use)) {
    color.use <- scPalette(ncol(net))
  }
  names(color.use) <- colnames(net)
  color.use.row <- color.use
  color.use.col <- color.use
  if (remove.isolate) {
    idx1 <- which(Matrix::rowSums(net) == 0)
    idx2 <- which(Matrix::colSums(net) == 0)
    if (length(idx1) > 0) {
      net <- net[-idx1, ]
      color.use.row <- color.use.row[-idx1]
    }
    if (length(idx2) > 0) {
      net <- net[, -idx2]
      color.use.col <- color.use.col[-idx2]
    }
  }
  mat <- net
  if (!is.null(row.show)) {
    mat <- mat[row.show, ]
    color.use.row <- color.use.row[row.show]
  }
  if (!is.null(col.show)) {
    mat <- mat[, col.show]
    color.use.col <- color.use.col[col.show]
  }
  if (min(mat) < 0) {
    color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(min(mat), 0, max(mat)), 
                                   c(color.heatmap[1], "#f7f7f7", color.heatmap[2]))
    colorbar.break <- c(round(min(mat, na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", 
                                                                      "\\1", min(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1), 0, round(max(mat, 
                                                                                                                      na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", "\\1", 
                                                                                                                                                     max(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1))
  }
  else {
    if (length(color.heatmap) == 3) {
      color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(0, min(mat), max(mat)), 
                                     color.heatmap)
    }
    else if (length(color.heatmap) == 2) {
      color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(min(mat), max(mat)), 
                                     color.heatmap)
    }
    else if (length(color.heatmap) == 1) {
      color.heatmap.use = (grDevices::colorRampPalette((RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 9, 
                                                                                 name = color.heatmap))))(100)
    }
    colorbar.break <- c(round(min(mat, na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", 
                                                                      "\\1", min(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1), round(max(mat, 
                                                                                                                   na.rm = T), digits = nchar(sub(".*\\.(0*).*", "\\1", 
                                                                                                                                                  max(mat, na.rm = T))) + 1))
  }
  df.col <- data.frame(group = colnames(mat))
  rownames(df.col) <- colnames(mat)
  df.row <- data.frame(group = rownames(mat))
  rownames(df.row) <- rownames(mat)
  col_annotation <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = df.col, col = list(group = color.use.col), 
                                      which = "column", show_legend = FALSE, show_annotation_name = FALSE, 
                                      simple_anno_size = grid::unit(0.2, "cm"))
  row_annotation <- HeatmapAnnotation(df = df.row, col = list(group = color.use.row), 
                                      which = "row", show_legend = FALSE, show_annotation_name = FALSE, 
                                      simple_anno_size = grid::unit(0.2, "cm"))
  ha1 = rowAnnotation(Strength = anno_barplot(rowSums(abs(mat)), 
                                              border = FALSE, gp = gpar(fill = color.use.row, col = color.use.row)), 
                      show_annotation_name = FALSE)
  ha2 = HeatmapAnnotation(Strength = anno_barplot(colSums(abs(mat)), 
                                                  border = FALSE, gp = gpar(fill = color.use.col, col = color.use.col)), 
                          show_annotation_name = FALSE)
  if (sum(abs(mat) > 0) == 1) {
    color.heatmap.use = c("white", color.heatmap.use)
  }
  else {
    mat[mat == 0] <- NA
  }
  ht1 = Heatmap(mat, col = color.heatmap.use, na_col = "white", 
                name = legend.name, bottom_annotation = col_annotation, 
                left_annotation = row_annotation, top_annotation = ha2, 
                right_annotation = ha1, cluster_rows = cluster.rows, 
                cluster_columns = cluster.rows, row_names_side = "left", 
                row_names_rot = 0, row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size), 
                column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size), column_title = title.name, 
                column_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size.title), 
                column_names_rot = 90, row_title = "Sources (Sender)", 
                row_title_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size.title), row_title_rot = 90, 
                heatmap_legend_param = list(title_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size, 
                                                            fontface = "plain"), title_position = "leftcenter-rot", 
                                            border = NA, legend_height = unit(20, "mm"), labels_gp = gpar(fontsize = font.size), 
                                            grid_width = unit(2, "mm")))
  return(ht1)
}


environment(netVisual_heatmapCustom) <- asNamespace('CellChat')

I then try running this and it gives the error Error in grDevices::col2rgb(colors) : invalid color name 'Reds'.
p1 <- netVisual_heatmapCustom(cellchat, comparison = c(1,2), font.size=3, font.size.title=4)
p2 <- netVisual_heatmapCustom(cellchat, comparison = c(1,2), measure = "weight",font.size=3,font.size.title=4)
p <- p1 + p2
pdf(file=paste(exDir, "/",today,"heatmap.pdf",sep=""), width=5.25, height=2.75)
plot(p)
dev.off()

Even when I create the custom function without changing anything in the source code the error persists. Suggestions for how to fix would be appreciated. If I check whether "Reds" is recognized outside of this function, it works.
grDevices::colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "Reds"))(100)
  [1] "#FFF5F0" "#FEF3ED" "#FEF1EB" "#FEEFE8" "#FEEEE6" "#FEECE3" "#FEEAE1"
  [8] "#FEE9DF" "#FEE7DC" "#FEE5DA" "#FEE4D7" "#FEE2D5" "#FEE0D2" "#FDDECF"
 [15] "#FDDBCB" "#FDD8C7" "#FDD5C3" "#FDD2BF" "#FDCFBB" "#FCCCB7" "#FCC9B3"
 [22] "#FCC6AF" "#FCC3AB" "#FCC0A7" "#FCBDA3" "#FCBAA0" "#FCB69C" "#FCB398"
 [29] "#FCB094" "#FCAC90" "#FCA98D" "#FCA689" "#FCA285" "#FC9F81" "#FC9C7D"
 [36] "#FC997A" "#FC9576" "#FC9272" "#FB8F6F" "#FB8B6B" "#FB8868" "#FB8565"
 [43] "#FB8262" "#FB7F5F" "#FB7B5B" "#FB7858" "#FB7555" "#FB7252" "#FB6E4E"
 [50] "#FB6B4B" "#FA6848" "#F96446" "#F86043" "#F75C41" "#F6583F" "#F5553C"
 [57] "#F4513A" "#F34D37" "#F24935" "#F14532" "#F04230" "#EF3E2E" "#EE3A2B"
 [64] "#EB372A" "#E83429" "#E53228" "#E32F26" "#E02C25" "#DD2924" "#DA2623"
 [71] "#D72422" "#D42120" "#D11E1F" "#CE1B1E" "#CB181D" "#C8171C" "#C5161B"
 [78] "#C2161B" "#BF151A" "#BC1419" "#B91319" "#B61318" "#B31217" "#B01117"
 [85] "#AD1016" "#A91016" "#A60F15" "#A30E14" "#9E0D14" "#990C13" "#940A12"
 [92] "#8F0912" "#8A0811" "#850710" "#800610" "#7B040F" "#76030E" "#71020E"
 [99] "#6C010D" "#67000D"


Session info is below.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: [path];  LAPACK version 3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: America/New_York
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] circlize_0.4.16             NMF_0.27                   
 [3] cluster_2.1.6               rngtools_1.5.2             
 [5] registry_0.5-1              ggalluvial_0.12.5          
 [7] reticulate_1.34.0           CellChat_1.6.1             
 [9] igraph_2.0.3                SeuratWrappers_0.3.5       
[11] monocle3_1.3.7              SingleCellExperiment_1.24.0
[13] clustree_0.5.1              ggraph_2.2.1               
[15] rcartocolor_2.1.1           presto_1.0.0               
[17] data.table_1.15.4           Rcpp_1.0.13                
[19] cowplot_1.1.3               viridis_0.6.4              
[21] viridisLite_0.4.2           RColorBrewer_1.1-3         
[23] clusterProfiler_4.10.1      org.Hs.eg.db_3.18.0        
[25] AnnotationDbi_1.64.1        EnhancedVolcano_1.20.0     
[27] ggrepel_0.9.4               DESeq2_1.42.1              
[29] SummarizedExperiment_1.32.0 Biobase_2.62.0             
[31] MatrixGenerics_1.14.0       matrixStats_1.0.0          
[33] GenomicRanges_1.54.1        GenomeInfoDb_1.38.1        
[35] IRanges_2.36.0              S4Vectors_0.40.2           
[37] BiocGenerics_0.48.1         lme4_1.1-35.5              
[39] Matrix_1.7-0                lubridate_1.9.3            
[41] forcats_1.0.0               stringr_1.5.1              
[43] purrr_1.0.2                 readr_2.1.5                
[45] tidyr_1.3.1                 tibble_3.2.1               
[47] tidyverse_2.0.0             dplyr_1.1.4                
[49] patchwork_1.2.0             Seurat_5.1.0               
[51] SeuratObject_5.0.2          sp_2.1-4                   
[53] scRepertoire_1.12.0         ggplot2_3.5.1              

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] R.methodsS3_1.8.2       goftest_1.2-3           Biostrings_2.70.3      
  [4] vctrs_0.6.5             spatstat.random_3.3-1   digest_0.6.36          
  [7] png_0.1-8               shape_1.4.6.1           deldir_2.0-4           
 [10] parallelly_1.37.1       permute_0.9-7           MASS_7.3-60            
 [13] reshape2_1.4.4          httpuv_1.6.12           foreach_1.5.2          
 [16] qvalue_2.34.0           withr_3.0.0             ggfun_0.1.5            
 [19] ggpubr_0.6.0            survival_3.7-0          memoise_2.0.1          
 [22] gson_0.1.0              systemfonts_1.1.0       tidytree_0.4.6         
 [25] zoo_1.8-12              GlobalOptions_0.1.2     pbapply_1.7-2          
 [28] R.oo_1.26.0             KEGGREST_1.42.0         promises_1.3.0         
 [31] evmix_2.12              httr_1.4.7              rstatix_0.7.2          
 [34] globals_0.16.3          fitdistrplus_1.2-1      miniUI_0.1.1.1         
 [37] generics_0.1.3          DOSE_3.28.2             zlibbioc_1.48.0        
 [40] polyclip_1.10-7         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.11 SparseArray_1.2.2      
 [43] xtable_1.8-4            doParallel_1.0.17       S4Arrays_1.2.0         
 [46] hms_1.1.3               irlba_2.3.5.1           colorspace_2.1-0       
 [49] ggnetwork_0.5.13        ROCR_1.0-11             spatstat.data_3.1-2    
 [52] magrittr_2.0.3          lmtest_0.9-40           later_1.3.2            
 [55] ggtree_3.10.1           lattice_0.22-6          spatstat.geom_3.3-2    
 [58] future.apply_1.11.2     SparseM_1.84-2          scattermore_1.2        
 [61] shadowtext_0.1.4        RcppAnnoy_0.0.21        pillar_1.9.0           
 [64] nlme_3.1-165            sna_2.7-2               iterators_1.0.14       
 [67] gridBase_0.4-7          compiler_4.3.1          RSpectra_0.16-2        
 [70] stringi_1.8.4           tensor_1.5              minqa_1.2.6            
 [73] plyr_1.8.9              crayon_1.5.3            abind_1.4-5            
 [76] gridGraphics_0.5-1      powerTCR_1.22.0         locfit_1.5-9.10        
 [79] graphlayouts_1.1.1      bit_4.0.5               fastmatch_1.1-4        
 [82] codetools_0.2-20        GetoptLong_1.0.5        plotly_4.10.2          
 [85] mime_0.12               splines_4.3.1           fastDummies_1.7.3      
 [88] HDO.db_0.99.1           blob_1.2.4              utf8_1.2.4             
 [91] clue_0.3-65             fs_1.6.4                listenv_0.9.1          
 [94] evd_2.3-7               gsl_2.1-8               ggsignif_0.6.4         
 [97] ggplotify_0.1.2         svglite_2.1.3           tzdb_0.4.0             
[100] network_1.18.2          tweenr_2.0.3            pkgconfig_2.0.3        
[103] tools_4.3.1             cachem_1.1.0            RSQLite_2.3.7          
[106] DBI_1.2.3               fastmap_1.2.0           scales_1.3.0           
[109] grid_4.3.1              ica_1.0-3               broom_1.0.6            
[112] coda_0.19-4.1           FNN_1.1.3.2             BiocManager_1.30.23    
[115] dotCall64_1.1-1         carData_3.0-5           RANN_2.6.1             
[118] farver_2.1.2            tidygraph_1.3.1         scatterpie_0.2.3       
[121] mgcv_1.9-1              VGAM_1.1-11             cli_3.6.3              
[124] leiden_0.4.3.1          lifecycle_1.0.4         uwot_0.1.16            
[127] backports_1.5.0         BiocParallel_1.36.0     timechange_0.3.0       
[130] gtable_0.3.5            rjson_0.2.21            ggridges_0.5.6         
[133] progressr_0.14.0        cubature_2.1.1          parallel_4.3.1         
[136] ape_5.8                 jsonlite_1.8.8          RcppHNSW_0.5.0         
[139] bitops_1.0-7            bit64_4.0.5             Rtsne_0.16             
[142] yulab.utils_0.1.4       vegan_2.6-6.1           spatstat.utils_3.0-5   
[145] BiocNeighbors_1.20.0    GOSemSim_2.28.1         spatstat.univar_3.0-0  
[148] R.utils_2.12.3          truncdist_1.0-2         lazyeval_0.2.2         
[151] shiny_1.8.1.1           htmltools_0.5.7         enrichplot_1.22.0      
[154] GO.db_3.18.0            sctransform_0.4.1       rappdirs_0.3.3         
[157] glue_1.7.0              spam_2.10-0             XVector_0.42.0         
[160] RCurl_1.98-1.12         treeio_1.26.0           gridExtra_2.3          
[163] boot_1.3-30             R6_2.5.1                labeling_0.4.3         
[166] stringdist_0.9.12       aplot_0.2.3             statnet.common_4.9.0   
[169] nloptr_2.0.3            DelayedArray_0.28.0     tidyselect_1.2.1       
[172] ggforce_0.4.2           car_3.1-2               future_1.33.2          
[175] rsvd_1.0.5              munsell_0.5.1           KernSmooth_2.23-24     
[178] htmlwidgets_1.6.4       fgsea_1.28.0            ComplexHeatmap_2.18.0  
[181] rlang_1.1.4             spatstat.sparse_3.1-0   spatstat.explore_3.3-1 
[184] remotes_2.5.0           Cairo_1.6-1             fansi_1.0.6   


I found the answer. In the source code, the condition if (min(mat) < 0) was true for my object, so it needed a two-color input for the code below. I was able to successfully run the code if I set color.heatmap to c("Blue","Red").
color.heatmap.use = colorRamp3(c(min(mat), 0, max(mat)), 
                               c(color.heatmap[1], "#f7f7f7", color.heatmap[2]))

